# Using an image in ejs template

Tags: web, development-environment

I want to use a photo downloded in the directory : public/image/logo.png.

and i want to use this image in secrets.ejs file

it is inside the directory : views/secrets.ejs[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IzBOZ.png)

please help me